# Ellipsis on html table

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's me again needing your help. I wanted to modify my current html table to highlight on hover. But for some reason, I can't get the ellipsis to work on this. On my current html table, the ellipsis works okay, but I wanted to add highlight on hover and it's not working. So I tried a different approach which is the script below. Highlight on hover is working but not the ellipsis.

I really need your help on this. Any expert tips/advice on how to make it work on my code below? Thank you in advance.

On click hightlight script:

```
<script>
if (!('select' in HTMLTableCellElement)) {
HTMLTableCellElement.prototype.select = function() {
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(this);
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 170px;
    height: 35px;
}

.table {font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:100%;border-width: 1px;border-color: #9dcc7a;border-collapse: collapse;}
.table th {font-size:12px;background-color:#abd28e;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #9dcc7a;text-align:left;}
.table tr {background-color:#ffffff;}
.table td {font-size:12px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #9dcc7a;}
.table tr:hover {background-color:#ffff99;}
.table td text-overflow:
.table td width: 225px;
.table td white-space: nowrap;


::selection {
background-color: orange;
color: blue;
}

</style>
```

Table sample:

```
<table class="table" border="1">
<tr><th>Header</th></tr>
<tr><td onclick="this.select()">This sentence should show ellipsis. This sentence should show ellipsis.</td><td onclick="this.select()">This sentence should show ellipsis. This sentence should show ellipsis.</td><td onclick="this.select()">This sentence should show ellipsis. This sentence should show ellipsis.</td><td onclick="this.select()">This sentence should show ellipsis. This sentence should show ellipsis.</td><td onclick="this.select()">This sentence should show ellipsis. This sentence should show ellipsis.</td></tr>
```

I'm looking forward to hearing back from you.

Best,

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid CSS. This:

```
.table td text-overflow:
.table td width: 225px;
.table td white-space: nowrap;
```

Should be this:

```
.table td { text-overflow: ellipsis;
            width: 225px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: Hi Malk, 

Thank you for your response. I actually tried that, but for some reason it doesn't actually show ellipsis. It instead overlaps with the texts on the table to the right. I'm not sure why since I set the table-layout: fixed.

Any idea why it happens?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you got it. You need `overflow:hidden` in addition to the nowrap for the ellipsis to kick in. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it! I just changed my CSS into this:

```
    <style type="text/css">

table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 170px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:100%;border-width: 1px;border-color: #9dcc7a;border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
    font-size:12px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #9dcc7a;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 225px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

table th {
    font-size:12px;background-color:#abd28e;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #9dcc7a;text-align:left;   
}

#table tr {background-color:#ffffff;}
#table tr:hover {background-color:#ffff99;}

::selection {
background-color: orange;
color: blue;
}

    </style>
```

Thanks for the idea Malk!